# Appropriate way to not display adsense ads

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, adsense

I am trying to hide an adsense ad unit on smaller screen sizes for responsive design purposes.

I am aware of https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438
which indicates you are allowed to use css media queries to hide a unit as follows:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) { .adslot_1 { display: none; } }
```

I have tried that but keep on getting the following error for the screen sizes that I don't display the ads on:

```
"Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto"
```

I find the following JavaScript solution much simpler and would prefer to use it instead of the media queries. I just add a test and do not call the adsense code unless the screen size is a sufficient size. It solves the error I was getting and I imagine it will save a request to the adsense servers as well(full disclosure: I do not understand the adsense code at all).

```
if ( $( window ).width() >= 600 ) {
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
```

Would an implementation like the above violate any of the programs policies/guidelines? Is it a reasonable and appropriate way to not display the ad units on certain screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Check this website out, there you can find ready to use scripts to detect if the user is on mobile or desktop, that way you can tell if he is on mobile and hide the Adsense block, or even better, you can call a "Responsive AD ID" from the Google Adsense, which is also recommended for mobile by Adsense itself.

If you still need a more simple way to detect if the user in on mobile, try this out.

html.

```
<div class="my_responsive_add">
    your ad
</div>
```

and css.

```
.my_responsive_add {
    display:inline;
}

@media (max-width:@maxResponsiveWideWidth){
    .my_responsive_add {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to not hide the AD, and use the  responsive ad, as it will look good on mobile users, and that way you can get clicks from mobile users.

To answer your question, I believe that by hiding the AD, it will not violate any of the program policies as far as I know, since that specific AD will not get any Clicks at all and it will remain "quiet" and will not drag attention.

Hope this helps a little, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is pretty much what I have already tried. My question is more about if the program policy allows me to use the alternative method outlined in my question.

Comment: I cannot say for sure, as I can be wrong, but you could send a support ticket at Adsense and wait for their response, I think that will be the best way to be 100% sure, they usually respond in few hours and up to a day or so, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [Modification of the AdSense ad code](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en) to read about adsense program policies particularly the 'Acceptable modifications'

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read through the link you provided and it recommends using only the css method I mentioned in my post, (which I am hoping to avoid using).  The policy specifically states the following is forbidden:  “Hiding ad units at anytime (e.g., display:none), unless you're implementing a responsive ad unit”  as I am trying to implement a responsive design you would think would be the answer to my question. However, I am still concerned because the policy only specifically prescribes the CSS display:none and does not address any other methods (specifically the one I am trying).

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still got the same problem with `display:none`. I fixed it by removing the data-ad-format parameter from  element. and keep everything else the same as documented by Google [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183363#zippy=%2Chiding-ads-for-specific-screen-sizes-example) at 'Hiding an ad unit' section, which means control the format using CSS media queries.

And it makes sense because you cannot set the format as auto when you specify the data-ad-format value and then control it by CSS.